# Where I get navigator.connection each effective type throughput or downlink information

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the network speed by using the new API , which is in experimental technology

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/effectiveType

this API will support slow2g,2g,3g,4g connection types for now.

Also I have written a fallback method if this feature is not supported in browser for finding the network speed.

My question is  I need to know what would be the default throughput of this default APIs connection types . is there any documentation to get the details? So I can emulate based on this in fallback code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](http://wicg.github.io/netinfo/)

### slow-2g

Minimum RTT (ms) : 2000

Maximum downlink (Kbps) : 50

Explanation : The network is suited for small transfers only such as text-only pages.

### 2g

Minimum RTT (ms) : 1400

Maximum downlink (Kbps) : 70

Explanation : The network is suited for transfers of small images.

### 3g

Minimum RTT (ms) : 270

Maximum downlink (Kbps) : 700

Explanation : The network is suited for transfers of large assets such as high resolution images, audio, and SD video.

### 4g

Minimum RTT (ms) :  0

Maximum downlink (Kbps) : ∞

Explanation : The network is suited for HD video, real-time video, etc.